# transmit to himself or transmit himself?

Tags: grammar

> He transmitted himself a disease through a syringe.
>
> He transmitted to himself a disease through a syringe.

Do you use to or not?

Comment: Do we use what?

Comment: We usually say "[Using a syringe] he (deliberately/intentionally) _infected_ himself with a disease."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "transmit" and "to", the word order should be
"He transmitted a disease to himself with a syringe."

"Transmitted himself" sounds as if "himself" is a direct object, as in

> He transmitted himself to an alternate galaxy with the first available exponder.

A verb that can have *himself* as an indirect object would be "gave":

> He gave himself a disease with a syringe.